# executeQuery() making the program hang

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm working on a database with three tables:
[image: img]

I want to insert a new record in such a way that 1st the information is added in `DonorInformation` & `NeedyInformation`. Then after taking primary ids from both the record should be inserted in to `Donation` table.

I have done the following to achieve this, but its displaying no error and hangs on save button. Kindly help.

[image]

Code:

```
public int insertDonorPersonal() throws SQLException{
int id=0;
      try {
          String urlDB= System.getProperty("user.dir").concat("\\database.accdb");
          con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+urlDB+";memory=true");
          stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

          //Inserting in Donor Information
          String SQLString = "INSERT INTO DonerInformation(DonorName,PhoneNumber,Address,City,BloodGroup)VALUES('" 
                  +DonorName.getText()+ "','" +PhoneNumber.getText()+ "','"+Address.getText()+"','"
                  + City.getText()+"','"+BloodGroup.getText()+"' )";
          stmt.executeUpdate(SQLString);
          rs=stmt.executeQuery("Select * from DonerInformation");
          rs.last(); 
          id= rs.getInt("DonorID");
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(addNewInternal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }finally{
      stmt.close();rs.close();con.close();
      }
      return id;

}

private void saveBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
   try {
       int id= insertDonorPersonal();
        String urlDB= System.getProperty("user.dir").concat("\\database.accdb");
          con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+urlDB+";memory=true");

     PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Donation(DonationDate,DonatedAmount,PaidBy,CheckNo,DonorID,NeedyID)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,? )");

        DateFormat sysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        String date = sysDate.format(jXDatePicker1.getDate()).toString();
         java.util.Date passDate= sysDate.parse(date);
         s.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(passDate.getTime())); //DonationDate
        s.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble(Amount.getText()));//DonatedAmount
        s.setString(3, comboS.getSelectedItem().toString());//PaidBy
        s.setString(4, CheckNo.getText());//CheckNo
        s.setInt(5, id);//DonorID
           s.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(needyTable.getValueAt(needyTable.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString()));//NeedyID

       s.executeUpdate();
        s.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Save Succesfull");
        resetComponents();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {  
    ex.printStackTrace();
} 
   finally{
       try {
          con.close();
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(addNewInternal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: Please add relevant information to your question itself, not as external resources.

Comment: there is no external resource added. I have posted the code that showing no error but also not working

Comment: Can you please specify what actually "hangs"? What do you mean by this?

Comment: Means the frame just hangs and then I have to stop the program from netbeans output pane

Comment: You should start be telling use where it hangs, What I can think of is the method insertDonorPersonnal that, I guess, create a connection too in his scope. Are you closing it correctly. Is the insert working ? Use debbuger to find where you code start to wait (probably the connection for a few seconds)

Comment: The method insertDonorPersonal() is working fine. Program hangs at s.executeUpdate();. I have even debugged it... All the values are coming correctly from database. Even then it just hangs at s.executeUpdate().

Answer (score 0):

Please make the scope of following variables local in the both of the methods `insertDonorPersonal()` and `saveBActionPerformed()`

1. java.sql.Connection con;
2. java.sql.Statement stmt; (unused in `saveBActionPerformed()`)
3. java.sql.ResultSet rs;
4. java.sql.PreparedStatement s; (only in `saveBActionPerformed()`)

Please remove following snippets from: `saveBActionPerformed()`

1. `stmt =
   con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);`
2. `stmt.close();`

Please look at the definition of the method `resetComponents();`. This method may be responsible for hanging up your program.

Comment: removed as suggested. Method resetComponent(); is just clearing all fields. But the compiler hangs at s.executeUpdate(); It doesnot go further so resetComponent() is not even read

Comment: How does this answer the question?